# pandas excel data read with incorrect output -no getting all the tabular data from excel plus pandas "FutureWarning" Error from "usecols" parameter

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote the following function (which could be made more efficient) to traverse my project directory: `' ../data/test_input'`  using os.listdir() and read my data files (10 in total) with the shapes of the data matrixes ranging from 4X4, 6X6, 8X8, ..., 22X22.

Below is a snippet of the excel tabular data. The same tabular set goes for the 6X6, 8X8, ..., 22X22
[image: Excel sample data file ("ex_4.xlsx")]

My goal is that the function returns a tuple of `df_4, df_6, df_8, df_10, df_12, df_14, df_16, df_18, df_20, df_22` which I could loop over and perform a few preprocessing before feeding them individually to my model.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import re


def read_files(file_name, loc_list=None):
    if loc_list is None:
        loc_list = []
    for itm in loc_list: 
        if itm == 4:
            df_4 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=4, usecols=range(1, 5))
            df_4.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_4.columns) + 1)]
            df_4.index = df_4.index + 1
            # loc_list.remove(itm)

        elif itm == 6:
            df_6 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=6, usecols=range(1, 7))
            df_6.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_6.columns) + 1)]
            df_6.index = df_6.index + 1
            # loc_list.remove(itm)

        elif itm == 8:
            df_8 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=8, usecols=range(1, 9))
            df_8.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_8.columns) + 1)]
            df_8.index = df_8.index + 1

        elif itm == 10:
            df_10 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=10, usecols=range(1, 11))
            df_10.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_10.columns) + 1)]
            df_10.index = df_10.index + 1

        elif itm == 12:
            df_12 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=12, usecols=range(1, 13))
            df_12.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_12.columns) + 1)]
            df_12.index = df_12.index + 1

        elif itm == 14:
            df_14 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=14, usecols=range(1, 15))
            df_14.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_14.columns) + 1)]
            df_14.index = df_14.index + 1

        elif itm == 16:
            df_16 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=16, usecols=range(1, 17))
            df_16.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_16.columns) + 1)]
            df_16.index = df_16.index + 1

        elif itm == 18:
            df_18 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=18, usecols=range(1, 19))
            df_18.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_18.columns) + 1)]
            df_18.index = df_18.index + 1

        elif itm == 20:
            df_20 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=20, usecols=range(1, 21))
            df_20.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_20.columns) + 1)]
            df_20.index = df_20.index + 1

        elif itm == 22:
            df_22 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=22, usecols=range(1, 23))
            df_22.columns = [k for k in range(1, len(df_22.columns) + 1)]
            df_22.index = df_22.index + 1

    return df_4, df_6, df_8, df_10, df_12, df_14, df_16, df_18, df_20, df_22


breaking_point = 0

loca_list = []
[loca_list.append(int(z)) for fname in os.listdir('../data/test_input') for z in re.findall('[0-9]+', fname)]
loca_list = sorted(loca_list)

breaking_point = 0

# TODO - perhaps consider mass read of data from excel in the dir/listdir
for fname in os.listdir('../data/test_input'):
    if fname.endswith('.xlsx') and re.findall('[0-9]+', fname) and 'ex' in fname:
        df_tuple = read_files('../data/test_input/' + fname, loc_list=loca_list)  # TODO

breaking_point = 1

# print the shape of df_tuple to inspect
for tuP in df_tuple:
    print(tuP.shape)

breaking_point = 2

for tuP in df_tuple:
    print('------------------ \n')
    print(tuP)
```

my expected output is to have a pandas df for each of the above-listed returned values. Instead, I am getting the following result, which is not what I want.

```
(4, 4)
(6, 6)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)
(8, 8)

------------------ below is correct as expected:
      1     2     3     4
1  9999  1606  1410   330
2  1096  9999   531   567
3   485  2322  9999  1236
4   960   496   700  9999

------------------ also correct as expected:
      1     2     3     4     5     6
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999

------------------ correct as expected:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 10 X 10:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 12 X 12:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 14 X14:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 16 X16:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 18 X 18:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 20 X 20:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999

------------------ below is from wrong; expected 22 X 22:
      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
1  9999  1606  1410   330    42   539   626   652
2  1096  9999   531   567  1359    29   846   481
3   485  2322  9999  1236    28   290   742   180
4   960   496   700  9999   650   904   416  1149
5   626   780  1367   696  9999   220   329   828
6   631  1218  1486  1163    24  9999   416  1057
7   657   460   819   733   761  1265  9999   463
8  1102   376   566  1324   409  1168   743  9999


Also, I am getting the following panda "FutureWarning" message:
```

FutureWarning: Defining usecols with out of bounds indices is deprecated and will raise a ParserError in a future version.
df_12 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=12, usecols=range(1, 13))

FutureWarning: Defining usecols with out of bounds indices is deprecated and will raise a ParserError in a future version.
df_14 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=14, usecols=range(1, 15))

...

FutureWarning: Defining usecols with out of bounds indices is deprecated and will raise a ParserError in a future version.
df_22 = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, nrows=22, usecols=range(1, 23))

I have also looked up this "FutureWarming" online several times but did not find the correct remedy for my issue.

I shall be glad if someone could help point out my mistake to me as I have already spent a lot of time tracking the error but to no avail.

Comment: My first port of call would be to ensure that you are discovering the files you expect to and that they contain the data expected.  The warning reads as though you're passing the 8x8 dataset from the files that should be 10x10.  ie, it's trying to read the 10x10 with an 8x8 matrix in excel.

Comment: @AndyMitchell I have checked all that and everything looks good. But the issue still persisist.

Comment: It still looks as though it's sticking on 'elif itm==8'.  Put a print statement in, for example 'elif itm==10'.  If the print statement gets triggered, the problem would be with the data it's calling as the read_excel call looks ok.  Have you also tried manually calling one of the incorrect dataframes without the additional logic?

Comment: @AndyMitchell yes, I have tried. The print statement was triggered. But why would the issue be with the data being called though? It is in the same format and shape as the 4 X 4, 6 X 6, ..., n X n matrices of data.

Comment: @AndyMitchell you're correct, it is getting stuck at 'elif==8' level. I am not sure at this moment what may be causing the 10 x 10 and higher matrixes not to read as expected during the function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re


def create_tuple_list(fpath):
    tuple_list = [(fname, int(z)) for fname in os.listdir(fpath) for z in re.findall('[0-9]+', fname) if
                  fname.endswith('.xlsx') and 'ex' in fname and re.findall('[0-9]+', fname)]

    return tuple_list


def main():
    # define file path
    dirpath = '../data/test/'

    # function call
    dtup_list = create_tuple_list(dirpath)

    for tuP in dtup_list:
        fname = tuP[0]
        nbr = tuP[1]

        df_c = pd.read_excel(dirpath + fname, sheet_name='Sheet1', skiprows=1, usecols=range(nbr + 1))
        df_c.index = df_c.index + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```